# The controls added to Document Action Pane of the Excel Customization is not functioning when the Excel is added to the ExcelViewer user control

Tags: c#, vsto

I am working with excel customization created with VSTO. My requirement is to open the locally saved excel customization file using C# windows form application and embed this excel customization file to the Viewer control. This viewer control should be placed in the windows form.

I have followed below steps.

1. Downloaded Excel Viewer control from http://excelviewer.codeplex.com.
2. Created a C# Windows application project.
3. Included the downloaded Excel Viewer control to the above project.
4. Build the project.
5. Drag and dropped the Excel Viewer control to the form.
6. In the Form constructor I have called `OpenFile(string filename)` method resided in    ExcelViewer class.
   Ex: *excelViewer1.OpenFile(@"C:\ ABC.xlsx");*

After following the above steps I am able to embed and show the excel file within the viewer control that is placed in a form, **BUT I cannot work with the any controls added in the Document Action Pane.** In my customization I have few buttons and if I click one of those the expected action is **not performed**.

Can anyone suggest me what type of changes needs to be done to fully work with controls in the Document Action Pane, when I embed the excel customization within a viewer control?